# npm shrinkwrap contains paths to localhost

Tags: npm, shrinkwrap, npm-shrinkwrap

After running `npm shrinkwrap` I find that we have many references to localhost:

```
  egrep localhost npm-shrinkwrap.json 
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/constants-browserify/-/constants-browserify-0.0.1.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/https-browserify/-/https-browserify-0.0.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/path-browserify/-/path-browserify-0.0.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/pbkdf2-compat/-/pbkdf2-compat-2.0.1.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/ripemd160/-/ripemd160-0.2.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/sha.js/-/sha.js-2.2.6.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/shimmer/-/shimmer-1.1.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/tty-browserify/-/tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/utils-merge/-/utils-merge-1.0.0.tgz"
  "resolved": "http://localhost:4873/vm-browserify/-/vm-browserify-0.0.4.tgz"
```

Turns out these references are also in the raw node_modules:

```
egrep 'localhost:4873' node_modules/ -r 
node_modules/path-browserify/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/path-browserify/-/path-browserify-0.0.0.tgz",
node_modules/utils-merge/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/utils-merge/-/utils-merge-1.0.0.tgz",
node_modules/ripemd160/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/ripemd160/-/ripemd160-0.2.0.tgz",
node_modules/constants-browserify/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/constants-browserify/-/constants-browserify-0.0.1.tgz",
node_modules/tty-browserify/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/tty-browserify/-/tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz",
node_modules/vm-browserify/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/vm-browserify/-/vm-browserify-0.0.4.tgz",
node_modules/shimmer/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/shimmer/-/shimmer-1.1.0.tgz",
node_modules/https-browserify/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/https-browserify/-/https-browserify-0.0.0.tgz",
node_modules/pbkdf2-compat/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/pbkdf2-compat/-/pbkdf2-compat-2.0.1.tgz",
node_modules/sha.js/package.json:  "_resolved": "http://localhost:4873/sha.js/-/sha.js-2.2.6.tgz",
```

So this means I'm getting a lot of fetch and retry errors when we install:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://localhost:4873/constants-browserify/-/constants-browserify-0.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
npm ERR! fetch failed http://localhost:4873/https-browserify/-/https-browserify-0.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4873
...
```

This can't be right.  What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Are you running a local npm server?

Comment: Looks like you're running https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia

Comment: No local server... Also `npm get registry` return `https://registry.npmjs.org/` so that is not pointing to localhost...

Comment: No local server running: ```telnet localhost 4873
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused```

Comment: You probably had that running when you first installed the packages.

Comment: Someone else ran the `npm shrinkwrap` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I frequently switch between registries. The solution was to run `npm cache clear` before installing/shrinkwrapping.